# Многомерные структуры в JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Только начал изучать JS. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в коде и почему не выводится ничего на экран? Вроде как пытался вывести все вложенные элементы

```
let data = [
    {
        1: [
            'data111',
            'data112',
            'data113',
        ],
        2: [
            'data121',
            'data122',
            'data123',
        ],
    },
    {
        1: [
            'data211',
            'data212',
            'data213',
        ],
        2: [
            'data221',
            'data222',
            'data223',
            'data224',
        ],
        3: [
            'data231',
            'data232',
            'data233',
            'data234',
            'data235',
        ],
    },
    {
        1: [
            'data411',
            'data412',
            'data413',
        ],
        2: [
            'data421',
        ],
    },
];
for (let num of data) {
    for (let a in data[num]) {
        for (let b of data[num][a]) {
            document. write(data[num][a][b] + '<br>');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: определись, ты либо используешь `of` либо `in`. А то ты не понимаешь что где.....в целом, ознакомься с отладкой из ответа дубликата и вперёд покорять вершину исправления косяка

Comment: в for...of  - num не ключ, а элемент массива. то есть в следующей строке надо писать  for (let a in num)

Comment: о, помогло, спасибо)